# how to hide and show textbox when checking/unchecking a radio button in a razor page?

Tags: jquery, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

**here is my radio button:**

```
<label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Type</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label class="container">
                        Reward
                        <input name="IsReward" type="radio" asp-for="IsReward" value="True" class="sb-isReward">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                    <span asp-validation-for="IsReward" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <label class="container">
                        Fine
                        <input name="IsReward" type="radio" asp-for="IsReward" value="False" >
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>

                </div>
```

**the textbox I want to show or hide when clicking on "reward" or "fine" option :**

```
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="CostReward" class="form-control sb-digit sb-isRewardTypeDiv">
                    <span asp-validation-for="CostReward" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
```

**and finally my jQuery codes that do not work:**

```
$('.sb-isGuilty').on('change', function () {
if (this.checked) {
    $('.sb-isGuiltyTypeDiv').show();
} else {
    $('.sb-isGuiltyTypeDiv').hide();
}
}).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing this issue because your event is always listening for a change on a radio button. And when you select a new radio button the event fires on that radio button.

so lets take a deeper look.

```
if (this.checked) {
    $('.sb-isGuiltyTypeDiv').show();
} else {
    $('.sb-isGuiltyTypeDiv').hide();
}
```

The above code gets executed every time a radio button gets selected. But when it's selected it's always checked, hence why the radio button always shows, it will never hit the false section of your if block.

try putting a console log above the if statement. `console.log(this.checked)` and inspect the output, you will see that it's always true.

What you should be doing is looking at the value of the selected radio button like the code block below.

```
$('.sb-isReward').on('change', function (e) {

if (e.target.value === "True") {

    $('.sb-isRewardTypeDiv').show();
} else {

    $('.sb-isRewardTypeDiv').hide();
}
}).trigger('change');
```

I also noticed that your selectors for the elements were wrong. Not sure if it was intentional, but i changed it in the code as well.

Here is a code pen of a working example : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gNYYjL

Hope this helps.